# Query part of an xml column as a result set

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

How can I grab just part of an xml column, and return it as it's own result set in SQL?

I have an xml file in my database that looks like this:

```
<main>
  <data>
    <rows>
      <_items>
        <columns>
          <values>
            <keyvaluepairs>
              <keyvaluepairofstringstring>
                <key>EVENT</key>
                <value>Wedding</value>              
              </keyvaluepairofstringstring>
              <keyvaluepairofstringstring>
                <key>DETAIL</key>
                <value>Smith-Wesson</value>              
              </keyvaluepairofstringstring>
            </keyvaluepairs>              
          </values>
        </columns>
        <columns>
          <values>
            <keyvaluepairs>
              <keyvaluepairofstringstring>
                <key>EVENT</key>
                <value>Reunion</value>              
              </keyvaluepairofstringstring>
              <keyvaluepairofstringstring>
                <key>DETAIL</key>
                <value>Class of 1996</value>              
              </keyvaluepairofstringstring>
            </keyvaluepairs>
          </values>
        </columns>
        <columns>
          <values>
            <keyvaluepairs>
              <keyvaluepairofstringstring>
                <key>EVENT</key>
                <value>Pie-throwing contest</value>              
              </keyvaluepairofstringstring>
              <keyvaluepairofstringstring>
                <key>DETAIL</key>
                <value>Cherry pies</value>              
              </keyvaluepairofstringstring>
            </keyvaluepairs>              
          </values>
        </columns>
      </_items>
    </rows>
  </data>
</main>
```

And I want to return the "rows" as a result set like this:

```
EVENT                   NAME
Wedding                 Smith-Wesson
Reunion                 Class of 1996
Pie-throwing contest    Cherry pies
...etc...
```

I am using the method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608879) to query out individual values, but that isn't enough to get all the data I really need.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Edit: To clarify, this xml is contained in a single row.  For example, to return the above xml, I would type

```
select my_xml_column from my_table;
```

Comment: Are you querying a single XML string, or over a set of rows? And your XML looks wrong too: SQL server doesn't accept this as XML data type.

Comment: XML error fixed.  I changed the tags and data around to anonymize it a bit, and goofed up an ending tag.  And this is contained in a column of type XML in sql server, contained in a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select X.N.value('(keyvaluepairofstringstring/value[../key = "EVENT"])[1]', 'varchar(100)') as EVENT,
       X.N.value('(keyvaluepairofstringstring/value[../key = "DETAIL"])[1]', 'varchar(100)') as NAME
from YourTable as T
  cross apply T.XMLCol.nodes('/main/data/rows/_items/columns/values/keyvaluepairs') as X(N)
```

Test here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/122873/

BTW, I had to fix your XML. There where some missing end tags.

Comment: You sir are awesome.  Thanks!  (and i fixed the xml end tag)